# Как поставить backgroundImage для ячейки в TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

У меня есть ячейки созданные с помощью массива и функции

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return TupesOfMenu.count
    }
```

Теперь для каждой ячейки мне нужно поставить задний фон, названия картинок у меня тоже в массиве

```
let typesOfImagesMenu = ["menu0", "menu1", "menu2", "menu3", "menu4", "menu5", "menu6"]
```

Теперь каким то образом мне нужно подставить к ячейке картинку

Comment: В качестве фона используется картинка или заливка определённого цвета?

Comment: У меня фон пустой, надо ему сзади, приделать картинку фоном, но не получается в ячейку поставить ImageView, т.к. у меня стоит переход к задним ячейкам, я был бы вам очень признателен, если бы вы ответили на мой вопрос шире https://vk.com/laptyriev

Comment: Вы лучше добавьте в вопрос побольше кода, Вы же не фрилансера ищете, который Вам всё приложение сделает.

Comment: Еше раз добрый день, я создал отдельный вопрос, где постарался точно задать свой вопрос, очень надеюсь вы мне поможете